# How to find text on page by using case insensitive regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, selenium-webdriver

I am writing some auto test using Web Driver to find text on page.

I have variable `address` - with value `Some one, Address`

And text on page `Some One, Address`

Difference only in **One** and **one**

but my regex not working

`...get(LINK, "regexp:(?i)("+address+")").exists();` // should return boolean

Please, help me to resolve this problem, 
Thanks

Comment: Show us your complete code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String base = "Some One, Address";
System.out.println(base.matches("(?i:.*address.*)"));
```